# Trouble running a batch when accessing the space file name

Tags: batch-file

When accessing the filename with space, something happens to the batch. The "v loop.txt" is treated as "v" so that the file "v" does not exist. How do I solve this problem?

```
@if not defined dbug echo off
set v=a;b;c;d;e 
echo %v%> "v lop.txt"
for /l %%a in (1,1,5) do (
    call :aa %%a
)
pause
:aa
for /f "tokens=%1 delims=;" %%i in ( "v lop.txt" ) do (
    echo %%i
)
if "%1"=="5" goto :end
goto :eof
```

Comment: To parse a file in quotes with `for /f` use option `usebackq` So `for /f "usebackq tokens=%1 delims=;" %%i in ( "v lop.txt" ) do (` should do. There is no label end in your code.

Comment: thanks very much! the problem is successfully sovled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LotPings says,To parse a file in quotes with for /f must use option usebackq.so the modified code is the following:
usebackq     Use the alternate quoting style:
             - Use double quotes for long file names containing spaces in "filenameset".
             - Use single quotes for 'Text string to process'
             - Use back quotes for `command to process`

#

```
@if not defined debug echo off
set v=a;b;c;d;e 
echo %v%> "v lop.txt"
for /l %%a in (1,1,5) do (
    call :aa %%a
)
pause
:aa
for /f "usebackq tokens=%1 delims=;" %%i in ( "v lop.txt" ) do (
    echo %%i
)
if "%1"=="5" goto :eof
goto :eof
```

#

Answer (score -1):

If directory or file names include spaces, then you need to wrap them in double quotes.

For example: "v loop.txt"